# How can I dump the most recent 1000 rows of all tables in a MySQL database for a development environment?

Tags: sql, database, mysql, development-environment

I'm looking to create a lighter development database.  If recently inserted rows aren't a requirement, this is a great solution:

```
mysqldump -u root -p -h hostname --single-transaction --opt --where="1 limit 1000" dbname > dump.sql
```

This dumps the first 1000 rows from each table in the database.

But how can I dump the **last** 1000 rows from each database?

It would be easy enough if each table had an `id` field (eg. `ORDER BY id DESC`), but this cannot be counted on.

Assume tables can reach up to 100MM rows. And a full database dump can measure in the 10-30GB range.

Comment: If there is no ordinal column or timestamp for the table then it's impossible to know what the "last" rows are

Comment: Also it is better database design to give tables identifiers of some kind.

Comment: What if they have ordinal columns or timestamps but they are not consistent between every table in a database?  For example, `table1` may have an `id`, but `table2` does not.  But `table2` has a `create_date` instead.  `Table3` has a `last_modified_date`.

Comment: Do you want to do this with `mysqldump`? (i.e. is using this tool mandatory?) - because you can easily achieve that without using it

Comment: You may end up destroying referential integredity by limiting to the most recent 1000...

Comment: And how does MySQL not know the most recent inserted rows?  It can limit by the first 1000 even without an ordinal or timestamp column just fine.  Why not the last 1000 rows?

Comment: @AlmaDo, it's not required. What do you recommend?

Comment: xQbert is right.  Strictly interpreted, he says your schema rules are broken.  But he also means your data won't connect any more.  1,000 of `this` won't have key-connections to 1,000 of `that`, so your dev replica will be useless.

Comment: First of all, in reality I'd be pulling the last 100k records from each table. It's rare that a development environment needs to go back further in time than this. And most of the association tables I'd expect to fully dump. And those few that only partially dump should never reach the depth of assn required because it would be going back in time. Am I misunderstanding the danger?

Comment: The LIMIT 1000 clause does not guarantee that you get the first 1000 rows of a table, though if you don't perform a mix of DELETEs and INSERTs, it may well be the case.  You really need to have a dump script that dumps everything except for certain large tables where you do something more selective without violating referential integrity.  The exact something is going to depend on your database design.  Dynamic SQL techniques can take care of the tedious parts.

Comment: Thanks @gwaigh, this is exactly what I ended up doing. Though I'm not exactly sure what you mean by Dynamic SQL techniques. Can you share an example? I built a shell script that dumped all but the large tables, and then dumped those individually, based on either ordinal columns (where available) or a temp table that stored associations during the dump. Thanks.

Comment: Look at questions tagged with [dynamic-sql] for examples.  It boils down to querying the database server for information about your database (eg. all the table names) in order to construct SQL statements that are run as a separate query.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- you need to give your rows a row id, and go from there

ALTER TABLE `tablename `    ADD COLUMN `row_id` INT NULL AFTER `some_column`;

update tablename JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r set row_id=@curRow := @curRow + 1 ;

-- throw the max row id into a variable:

set @max=(select max(row_id) from tablename );

-- delete or select whatever by that variable:

delete from tablename where row_id< @max-1000
```

Comment: But wouldn't this take a long time to dump, given that you need to iterate through every row of every table and assign a row id? I'm picturing running this on a table with 50MM records.

Comment: On further look, it seems like you're suggesting a full import, but then dumping all but the last 1000 rows. This defeats the purpose. The goal is super light dev databases with most recent data. Not a heavy full database dump and import that is reduced to a lighter size.  Some of our development environments don't even have enough space for a full dump and import. One of our dbs is 50GB. This means storing 50GB for the database, plus another 50GB for the dump (or 8GB for the gzip). That's asking a lot on an old 128gb SSD. Not much room for anything else. Was hoping for <5GB, or 500MB gz

Comment: by the same technique you can dump only the last 1000 rows by adding the JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r as a row id when you query the table. It will not go fast though. If you want a light dev DB, what I used to do was select every 10000's record by doing where right(row_id, 5)='00000'